# Get the first element from an array with mongodb java client

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a JavaScript code.

```
db.xxx.aggregate([
    {$project: {object:{$first:'$object.array'}, _id:0}}
])
```

I don't know how to overwrite it by java client.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
...
Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.project().andExclude("_id").???
)
```

And where to find the usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is TestDocument

```
public class TestArrayDocument {
    @Id
    String id;
    Integer[] x;
}
```

Inject MongoTemplate

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

This is aggregate method

```
  TypedAggregation<TestArrayDocument> aggregation  = Aggregation.newAggregation(TestArrayDocument.class,Aggregation
            .project()
            .andExclude("_id")
            .andExpression("first(x)").as("object"));

    List<Map> mapData=  mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(aggregation,Map.class)
            .getMappedResults();
```

x is your $object.array.

return in LinkedHashMap "object"=>"firstElement".